# Store String of one class into an object of another class

Tags: java, oop, tostring

I am working on a project that links books to their authors.The author info is part of the book class and it is an Author object in the book class and its data will become part of the book class. I have the author class:

```
public class Author {
    private String Name;
    private String email;
    private char gender;

    public Author( ) {
         Name="Emily";
        email="email@email.com";
        gender='f';
    }

    public String getName (){   
         return Name;
    }

    public void setName (String Name){
         this.Name=Name;
    }

    public String getEmail (){
         return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }

    public char getGender (){
         return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(char gender){
         this.gender=gender;
    }

    public String toString () {
        String x = "Name: " + Name + "email "  + "gender:  " + gender;
        return x;
     }
}
```

and the book class:

```
public class Book {
    private String name;
    private Author author;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Book (){
        name="Book Name";
        author=Author.toString();
        price=11.79;
        quantity=2;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public Author getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor () {
        this.author=author;
    }

    public double getPrice () {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice (double price) {
        this.price=price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity (int quantity) {
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    public String toString (){
        String x =  "Book is " + name + "Author and author info "+ author + "Price " + price + "Quantity " + quantity;
        return x;
    }
}
```

I need to store the contents of the `toString()` method in the Author variable in the book class as the author info. How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you want to store the Author objects toString in the book? Just call it when needed. (Which is exactly what you do in the books toString...)

Comment: *Unrelated:* You correct named all the other fields in lowercase, so why did you call it `Name` in the `Author` class? --- Also, you should work on your indentations. They are horrendous.

Comment: The String x with the author's info I want to take that info and put it in the Author object in the book class

Comment: You can't. The `author` field is either the `Author` object itself (which makes sense), or it is a `String` with the values (which makes no sense).

Comment: It's already there (*in* the Author instance); just do `author.toString()` if you want it.

Comment: No, you don't want that. You want a reference to the author of the book insde the book. So you want a field author, or type Author, inside Book. And you already have that. Whenver you need to transform the author of the book into a String, you can then call toString() on the author.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the value of the `toString()` method of the Author class, this would couple your classes unnecessarily and break one of the core principals of good OO design.

The `toString` method of the Author class should be responsible for presenting a sensible String representation of its state (which it seems to).  Your book class should do the same, delegating to classes it interacts with to do the same:

```
public String toString() {
   return "Book is " + name + "Author and author info "+ author.toString() + "Price " + price + "Quantity " + quantity;
}
```

As noted in the comments, you're already doing this in the code snippet posted in the question, your question implies that this this may have not been 'by design'. I would recommend researching Object Encapsulation and delegation.